# How do I prevent my proxy from showing the searched URL in the address bar?

Tags: python, html, url, encoding, proxy

I have a basic proxy website template and I edited it to my liking, how ever when I enter in a url it works but in the address bar it adds the url I typed in to the end. How do I encode it or stop it from appearing in the address bar?

If i was to go on facebook
it would say
http://haydensfunwebsite.appspot.com/www.facebook.com
I want the "www.facebook.com" part encoded or changed or something.

any help would be great!

this is the link for the template I used:
https://github.com/labnol/google-proxy/archive/v1.0.zip

If you could modify it and re upload it that would be great aswell!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for simple encoding and decoding.

```
<?php $encoded = base64_encode($string); ?>

<?php $decoded = base64_decode($encoded); ?>
```

Comment: do you know where I would type that in? Sorry, I'm very new to this kind of stuff! Thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: Sorry I thought this was written in PHP not Python. My answer is basically useless to you. Feel free to downvote.

Comment: I included the file I am using in the link feel free to check it out